# Intercepting calls to Java 8 lambda-expressions using Byte Buddy

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, byte-buddy

I try to intercept calls to methods and calls to Java 8 lambda expressions using a Byte Buddy `AgentBuilder` as follows:

```
static {
  final Instrumentation inst = ByteBuddyAgent.install();
  new AgentBuilder.Default()
        .type(ElementMatchers.nameContainsIgnoreCase("foo"))
        .transform((builder, typeDescription) ->
                builder.method(ElementMatchers.any())
                        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(LogInterceptor.class)))
        .installOn(inst);
}

public static class LogInterceptor {
  @RuntimeType
  public static Object log(@SuperCall Callable<?> superCall) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("yeah...");
    return superCall.call();
  }
}
```

I'm using Byte Buddy v0.7.1.

It can intercept the following `Runnable` (anonymous class):

```
FunnyFramework.callMeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from inner class");
    }
});
```

and of course any calls to objects defined as *normal* (non-anonymous) classes. But the interception does not work for lambda expression's like:

```
FunnyFramework.callMeLater(() -> {
    System.out.println("Hello from lambda");
});
```

How can I intercept also the lambda expression calls? There's no such thing as a *LambdaInterceptor* in Byte Buddy, as far as I know.

Comment: Instrumenting lambda expressions is now possible as of Byte Buddy 1.1.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Java virtual machine does not permit a transformation of a class files representing a lambda expression. Classes that represent lambda expressions are loaded by so-called [*anonymous class loaders*](https://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/entry/anonymous_classes_in_the_vm) (not to be confused with classical [*anonymous classes*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)) that inherit another class's security context, e.g. a class that is loaded with an anonymous class loader which binds the loaded class to another class `Foo` can access `private` methods of `Foo`. This loading happens explicitly using the `sun.misc.Unsafe` API.

Byte Buddy hooks into the [Java instrumentation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) which allows the application of `ClassFileTransformer`s to hook into a `ClassLoader`s loading process. As *anonymous class loaders* are not considered `ClassLoader`s in the common sense, the instrumentation API does not allow for such instrumentations and therefore prohibits the instrumentation of lambda expressions.

This is of course unfortunate for some use cases, but in most real-life applications, there is no real requirement for instrumenting lambda expression. Many real-world instrumentations are for example applied to methods that are annotated with a given annotation what is not possible to apply to lambda expressions or to classes that are more complex than a functional interface.

---

**UPDATE**: With Byte Buddy version 1.1.0, it is possible to instrument classes that represent lambda expressions. For this, Byte Buddy instruments the JVM's `LambdaMetafactory` and replaces the class generation with a custom definition. To activate this feature, execute the following step in the builder:

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
  .with(LambdaInstrumentationStrategy.ENABLED)
```

Note that this does only work with OpenJDK 8u40, in previous versions, there is a bug related to invokedynamic call sites that prevents this from working.

Comment: Is this strategy of instrumenting LambdaMetaFactory still true today (jdk 9+)

Comment: It gets increasingly more difficult but in general, yes, it still is applicable.

Comment: Why is it getting more difficult? Also I read you email chain with Oracle in 2016 in which they mention about directly instrumenting  bytes in class file, but since that’s bootstrap - no retransformation. Is that why you chose to delegate LambdaMetaFactory?

Comment: Instrumanting lambda expressions is considered bad practice so with future changes, this might become impossible alltogether.

Comment: Hmm... but like you said in your email - multiple profilers that provides visibility for various purposes all of a sudden can’t do so anymore if lambdas are not Instrumentable in the future. I wonder if it will actually get to that. Since it won’t be just the profilers but the people that also rely on them.

Comment: You can still instrument the methods that comtain the lambda code what might be how it needs to be done in the future.