# how to debug an internal error?

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, byte-buddy

So I have a class `Foo` that should eventually adjust and reload classes. It has a method for that, too:

```
private void redefineClass(String classname, byte[] bytecode) {
    ClassFileLocator cfl = ClassFileLocator.Simple.of(classname,bytecode);

    Class clazz;
    try{
        clazz = Class.forName(classname);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    Debug._print("REDEFINING %s",clazz.getName());

    new ByteBuddy()
            .redefine(clazz,cfl)
            .make()
            .load(clazz.getClassLoader(), ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent())
            ;
}
```

To test it, I simply load the classes from `.class` files to `byte[]` (using ASM)

```
private byte[] getBytecode(String classname){
    try {
        Path p = Paths.get(LayoutConstants.SRC_DIR).resolve(classname.replace(".","/") + ".class");
        File f = p.toFile();
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(is);
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr,0);
        cr.accept(cw,0);
        return cw.toByteArray();
    }catch(IOException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

and pass it on to `redefineClass` above.
Seems to work for quite a few classes ... not for all, though:

```
REDEFINING parc.util.Vector$1
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.InternalError: Enclosing method not found
    at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethod(Class.java:952)
    at sun.reflect.generics.scope.ClassScope.computeEnclosingScope(ClassScope.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.getEnclosingScope(AbstractScope.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.lookup(AbstractScope.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.findTypeVariable(CoreReflectionFactory.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitTypeVariableSignature(Reifier.java:165)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.TypeVariableSignature.accept(TypeVariableSignature.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:100)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:814)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeList$Generic$OfLoadedInterfaceTypes$TypeProjection.resolve(TypeList.java:722)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$LazyProjection.accept(TypeDescription.java:5308)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeList$Generic$AbstractBase.accept(TypeList.java:249)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.InstrumentedType$Factory$Default$1.represent(InstrumentedType.java:221)
    at net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy.redefine(ByteBuddy.java:698)
    at net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy.redefine(ByteBuddy.java:676)
    at parc.Foo.redefineClass(Foo.java:137)
```

disassembling `Vector$1` gives me `class Vector$1 implements java/util/Enumeration`, so that indicates it's this class:

```
/**
 * Returns an enumeration of the components of this vector. The
 * returned {@code Enumeration} object will generate all items in
 * this vector. The first item generated is the item at index {@code 0},
 * then the item at index {@code 1}, and so on.
 *
 * @return  an enumeration of the components of this vector
 * @see     Iterator
 */
public Enumeration<E> elements() {
    return new Enumeration<E>() {
        int count = 0;

        public boolean hasMoreElements() {
            return count < elementCount;
        }

        public E nextElement() {
            synchronized (Vector.this) {
                if (count < elementCount) {
                    return elementData(count++);
                }
            }
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Vector Enumeration");
        }
    };
}
```

except I still have no idea what to do with that information.

For some reason the instrumented code that was saved to file can be loaded and used but can't be REloaded.

How do I find out why?

EDIT: I should mention that the project I'm working on requires Java 7.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33912156/1319284  This question seems like a duplicate.

Comment: @kutchkern Interesting, thank you. But the project I'm working on requires Java7 and that doesn't have lambda expressions.

Comment: @User1291 What is the point of loading `byte[]` from file using ASM?
Why you not just load it with help of [`java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(p)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29)?

Comment: @User1291 lambda expressions are just anonymous inner classes, the point being that the problem is anonymous inner classes.

Comment: @User1291 never mind you are right and the referenced answer only deals with specifics of lambda expressions that don't necessarily apply to anonymous classes.

Comment: Which version of byte-buddy are you using?

Comment: @kutschkem that would be ``1.7.9``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested several Java versions and could not find any problems with `Class.getEnclosingMethod` and `Class.getGenericInterfaces` for a local class implementing a generic interface, like in the `Vector.elements()/Enumeration<E>` case. Perhaps, the problems arise, because the class file has already been manipulated.

But it seems that whatever the `ByteBuddy` frontend is doing under the hood involving `Class.getGenericInterfaces` is just overkill for your use case, as you have the intended result byte code already.

I suggest going one level down and use

```
ClassReloadingStrategy s = ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent();
s.load(clazz.getClassLoader(),
    Collections.singletonMap(new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(clazz), bytecode));
```

to skip these operations and just activate your byte code.

When the class loading strategy is based on `ClassReloadingStrategy.Strategy.REDEFINITION` you can also use

```
ClassReloadingStrategy s = ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent();
s.reset(ClassFileLocator.Simple.of(classname, bytecode), clazz);
```

as it will use the bytecode retrieved through the `ClassFileLocator` as base.

Comment: THANK you! It hadn't occured to me ``reset`` could be used in this way. The doc's "reset all classes **to their original definition**" discouraged me.

Comment: This is indeed a bug, the implicit choice should be retransformation as it is more universal. I also added a method for setting the strategy explicitly as an argument. The fixes will be part of Byte Buddy 1.7.11. In the mean time, you can also use `new ClassReloadingStrategy(ByteBuddyAgent.getInstrumentation(), Strategy.RETRANSFORMATION)`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the byte-buddy code, I assume that ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent() will return a ClassReloadingStrategy configured with Strategy.REDEFINITION, which does not support anonymous classes. Use Strategy.RETRANSFORMATION instead.

```
ClassReloadingStrategy strat = new ClassReloadingStrategy(
   (Instrumentation) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
                    .loadClass("net.bytebuddy.agent.Installer")
                    .getMethod("getInstrumentation")
                    .invoke(null), 
   Strategy.RETRANSFORMATION);
```

You may consider writing a bug report, the default behavior does not match the comment which says that the default is Strategy.RETRANSFORMATION.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm afraid that didn't change much for this particular error, which stayed the same.

Comment: @User1291 In that case, I advise you to go to github and file a bug report for your problem. It looks like it should work, but doesn't.